# Значение символа $ в css

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, переменные

В некоторых css файлах видел запись вида $. Что она значит?  И в чем отличие между css переменными, начинающимися на `--` и переменными, начинающимися на `$`?

Comment: Переменных, начинающихся на `$`, в css просто не существует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это переменная scss и ничего с css это не имеет.
Вот пример как его использовать:

```
$width: 5em;

// Вы можете обратиться к переменной в свойствах
#main {
  width: $width;
}
```

Comment: По сути, это символ, который говорит компилятору, что это переменная